# implement mobile views for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I want to set it up in a way that when a mobile phone uses my website, it will be redirected to a url with 'm' subdomain, but i will be using the same controllers, but just different views. I just need a general road map of how to implement something like that.

Comment: [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices) maybe useful.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to add a before filter in the application controller like

```
before_filter :detect_mobile_device

#Checking against the user agent
def detect_mobile_device       
   if request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
     redirect_to m.****.com
   end
end
```

Then onwards you can modify and utilize it to render different views, you can also use

```
 def is_mobile_device?   
   return request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
 end
```

For some browsers it might not work so you can use this gem

```
gem 'mobile-fu'
```